# No puedo usar la versión 10 de node me dice exit status 5: acceso denegado

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript, nvm

Hola buenas tardes estoy intentado usar node js 10 pero al momento de ejecutar nvm use 10.0.0 se me niega el acceso y me dice que no se puede crear un archivo que ya existe:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco mucho cualquier ayuda compañeros

Comment: Asegúrate de estar ejecutando `nvm use xxx` en una terminal con privilegios administrativos. Abre una powerShell como administrador y entonces ejecuta el comando.

Comment: Gracias Jaime, esa fue la solución

Comment: Agregué la respuesta para futuras referencias.

Comment: Listo brother gracias, muy amable la verdad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asegúrate de estar ejecutando `nvm use xxx` en una terminal con privilegios administrativos. Abre una `powerShell` como administrador y ejecuta el comando en ella. Eso solucionará el problema.